# Android Passing data from application to browser

Tags: android

In android, we can pass data from a browser to an application using `intent-filter`.
For example:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="twitter.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

And we can get the data from the browser as follows:

```
// Getting data for http://twitter.com/status/12345
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String scheme = data.getScheme(); // "http"
String host = data.getHost(); // "twitter.com"
List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
String first = params.get(0); // "status"
String second = params.get(1); // "12345"
```

My question is:
Is it possible to do it the other way around?
Let's say that I want to pass a String to a browser, is that possible?
If possible, how to do it?
I did some researches and the conclusion was for security issues it is not allowed.
I thought maybe there could be some walks around and that's why I decide to ask.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using a WebView?

If so, you can pass a url with parameters for HTTP GET, or you can url encode for HTTP POST.

Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html